# AVR IO Ports can not be global

Tags: c, compiler-errors, microcontroller, avr, atmelstudio

I was writing an AVR code on Atmel Studio and by mistake I forgot to write the IO port settings (DDRx , PORTx ,...etc) in the main , instead I put it outside the main as shown:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void delay_250ms();
uint8_t t_hr = 0 , t_min = 0 , t_sec = 0 , i = 0 , tempp;
uint8_t start_stopwatch = 0;
DDRA |= 0xFF;
PORTA = 0x00;
DDRD = 0x00;
PORTD |= 0xFF;
```

then I got that error:

> - expected `)` before `(` token
> - expected identifier or `(` before `volatile`
> - expected `)` before `(` token
> - expected identifier or `(` before `volatile`
> - expected `)` before `(` token
>     …

When I added them back to the main function there were no errors

The question is why I can't add them outside the main ?
Do I miss some point ?

Comment: Put relevant code in your question (copy-paste it, then select it and click the `{}` icon so it is correctly formatted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A line of code like `DDRA |= 0xFF` is a statement. It performs a specific action (like setting all the bits of `DDRA`) when it is executed.

A statement must appear in a function, so that it will be executed as part of that function. It can't be placed at the top level of a source file, because source files are not executed -- only functions are.

Comment: oh :O 
Thanks so much .

Comment: Source files are never executed anyway. The compiled and linked executable file - yes